# Рекурсивный и итеративний алгоритм факториала

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача такова: ввожу число - программа должна посчитать её факториал. Хочется это сделать и рекурсивно и итеративно

Вот как я это понимаю итеративно. Но что то не работает.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int factorial = 1;
    int namber = 0;
    for (int counter = namber; counter > 1; counter--)
    {
        cout << "введите номер факториала" << endl;
        cin >> namber;
        factorial = factorial* counter;
        cout << namber << "!=" << factorial;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот рекурсивно:

```
int main()
{
    int number=0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    for (int counter = number; counter <= 10; counter)
        cin >> number;
        cout << number << "! =" << factorial(number) << endl;

    return 0;

}

unsigned long factorial(unsigned long number)
{
    if (number <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return number*factorial(number - 1);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам следует вынести рекурсивное и итеративное вычисление факториала в отдельные функции.

Соответствующие программы могут, например, выглядеть следующим образом.

Для рекурсивного вычисления

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

unsigned long long recursive_factorial( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * recursive_factorial( n - 1 );
}    

int main()
{
    std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "Russian" );

    while ( true )
    {        
        std::cout << "Введите неотрицательное число для "
                     "вычисления факториала (0-выход): ";

        unsigned int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        std::cout << "Факториал " << n << " равен " << recursive_factorial( n ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Для итеративного вычисления

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

unsigned long long iterative_factorial( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned long long factorial = 1;

    for ( unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i++ ) factorial *= i;

    return factorial;
}

int main()
{
    std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "Russian" );

    while ( true )
    {        
        std::cout << "Введите неотрицательное число для "
                     "вычисления факториала (0-выход): ";

        unsigned int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        std::cout << "Факториал " << n << " равен " << iterative_factorial( n ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Вы можете использовать эти программы как шаблон для написания собственной программы.

Вы должны иметь в виду, что даже размер типа `unsigned long long int` ограничен, а потому не в состоянии вмещать вычисляемый факториал для всех заданных пользователем значений.

Об ограничениях на верхние значения для факториалов для целочисленных типов в C++ я написал в сообщении [по следующему адресу](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-0-0-1435264884)

Если вы хотите контролировать верхний предел вычисляемого значения, то вы можете, например, выбрасывать исключение. Для этого вам понадобится включить заголовок `<limits>`  и использовать стандартный класс `std::numeric_limits`, чтобы получить максимальное значение в том или ином целочисленном типе. Например,

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсивно вышло :)

```
unsigned long factorial(unsigned long);  

int main()  
{  
    int number;   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  
    cout << "Введите число" << endl;  
    cin >> number;  
    cout << number << "!=" << factorial(number) << endl;  
    return 0;  
}  

unsigned long factorial(unsigned long number)  
{  
    if (number <= 1)
        return 1;  
    else  
        return number*factorial(number - 1);
}
```

Итеративно:

```
int main()  
{  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  
    int factorial = 1;  
    int number = 0;  
    cout << "введите номер факториала" << endl;  
    cin >> number;  
    for (int counter = number; counter >= 1; counter--)  
    {  
        factorial = factorial* counter;  
    }  
    cout << number << "!=" << factorial;  
    return 0;  
}
```